# Why is Jquery AJAX and AngularJS Http Post returning different results?

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an action in my controller that does the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RetrieveTransactionStatuses() {
     throw new Exception("Test exceptioN");
     return this.Json(this.RetrieveStatusLines());
}
```

I am calling this method using the $.ajax() using jquery and $http in angular but it is returning different results.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Status/RetrieveTransactionStatuses',
    method:'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function() {
    console.log('success ajax');
}).fail(function () {
    console.log('fail ajax');
});



$http({url: '/Status/RetrieveTransactionStatuses', method: 'POST'})
.then(function (response) {
    // success
    console.log('on success Angular');
},
function () {
    console.log('on failure angular');
});
```

On my console, I read the results as:

'fail ajax'

'on success Angular'

Why are they returning different results as I expect the angular to fail because the action on the controller is throwing an exception?

Comment: Is there any $http interceptor involved?

Comment: what do you mean by $http interceptor?

Comment: Its kind of a set of hook methods for different stages of http calls. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http